# In Flutter,How to automate button without clicking after a period of time?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

The idea is to check sms gateway if it is ok or not  by sending a sms to a specific mobile number after every period of time. If I get response then it is all ok.

The problem is:

I can’t automate the button what I have to press. I want the button automatically clicked after a specific period of time that send request to the gateway.

Because it’s not possible for me to click the button after a period of time always.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use Future.delayed or Timer to do this. Depending on your code, you might need to do this in background. There are [various platform-specific solutions](http://pub.dev) for background code execution, which I will not be getting into.

Now, to the solution:

Future.delayed example

```
Future _delayedFuture = Future.delayed(
  const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  () {
    // Call some function after delay of 500ms
  },
);
```

Future.delayed cannot be cancelled, while timer can be.

Timer example:

```
Timer _timer = Timer(
  const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  () {
    // Call some function after delay of 500ms
  },
);
```

If you want to cancel timer, use `_timer.cancel()`

You can also run timer periodically, by using `Timer.periodic();`

Comment: Can i get more details explanation as i'm very noob regarding this.

Suppose I have a function called callService() which return the responded data from a server. Now I want this function to be called after every 60s periodically.

Comment: Timer _timer = Timer.periodic(
  const Duration(seconds: 60),
  () {
    callService(); 
  },
);